# SQLite Error : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) -iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, sqlite, grand-central-dispatch

When I am trying to insert data into my table, sometimes I get this error, and my app crashes!

[image]

Crash logs :

```
Observation(4001,0x10dd67000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff3a917100: Non-aligned pointer being freed (2)
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
2016-11-03 11:12:03.063 Observation[4001:46477] Insertion failed !


Printing description of dbpath:
(const char *) dbpath = 0x00007fff3b8a5690 "/Users/macbt/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0EEC62AE-6DF0-4FC4-9D30-1EB90CB695A5/data/Containers/Data/Application/A709E729-3162-4CC8-B9FF-2F22A32FC6BD/Documents/ObservationDB.db"


Printing description of insertSQL:
insert into table_hazard (id, name, modifiedDate) values ("1","Hazard", "03/11/2016 11:12:03 AM")


Printing description of insert_stmt:
(const char *) insert_stmt = 0x00007fff3b9291a1 "insert into table_hazard (id, name, modifiedDate) values (\"1\",\"Hazard\", \"03/11/2016 11:12:03 AM\")"
```

Comment: Are you doing any db operation in background thread?

Comment: Ya, i am fetching data in Background ,,,,and storing in Database
under this Block       " dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                       
 
}); "

Comment: Is there any database operation going in parallel threads. I think it might be due to accessing database in different threads at the same time

Comment: i think so , but   how can Resolve this problem ??

Comment: you can use `@synchroinized` block to solve this problem. Wherever you are accessing db, write the code for db operation in `@synchonized` block. This might solve the problem. Please let me know if you need other details like implementation etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this type of problems is , you may be missing  below statement.

```
 sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
```

after every

```
sqlite3_open()
sqlite3_prepare_v2()
```

we should always finalize the statement  and close the database before return statement. Don't leave database open.
without finalizing statement and without closing Database if you try to again open it `sqlite3_open()`

or

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2()
```

this will result in  `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`  regarding database .

For example:

```
-(BOOL) insertDropdownValues:(NSString *)tableName
                       andId:(NSInteger) dID
                        name:(NSString*) name
                modifiedDate:( NSString*) modifiedDate {

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (%@, %@, %@) values (\"%ld\",\"%@\", \"%@\")",tableName,ID,NAME,MODIFIED_DATE, dID,name,modifiedDate];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];


        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);


        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {

            NSLog(@"Inserted SuccessFull");
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);

            return YES;
        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"Insertion failed !");
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(database);

            return NO;
        }

    }

    sqlite3_reset(statement);
    return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Try to set a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break`.
- Set your variables to nil after you release them.
- Go carefully over all the calls to sqlite3_prepare_v2 instructions and make sure that the matching `sqlite3_finalize` is called for each one of them.
- Add `@synchroinized` block to make it thread safe

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might be due to accessing database in different threads at the same time. You can use thread lock to solve this problem. You can write the code for database operations inside `@synchronized` block for solving this problem. It can be implemented as follows.

```
@synchronized (self) {
    // do the operation
}
```

Please let me know if it either works or doesn't work. Feel free to suggest edits.

Answer (score 0):

Go for Fmdb for sqlite implementation https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb it's very easy to understand