# iOS App crashes on sqlite3_reset with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, sqlite

My iOS app terminates in Xcode simulator due to EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP) error on following line

```
sqlite3_reset(stmt);
```

The complete block of code is

```
-(BOOL)containsPendingSignature
{
sqlite3_stmt *stmt = nil;

const char* sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM pending_signatures";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
NSAssert1(0, @"Error:'%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


int rowCount = 0;
if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    rowCount = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
}

sqlite3_reset(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
return rowCount > 0;
}
```

Could any one please suggest what is wrong here, thank you in advance.

Comment: it is because you are not closing DataBase after every use .....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40394876/sqlite-error-exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0-ios  have a look at this ,,,,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of this type of problems is , you may be missing below statement.

```
 sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
```

after every

```
sqlite3_open()
sqlite3_prepare_v2()
```

we should always finalize the statement and close the database before return statement. Don't leave database open.
without finalizing statement and without closing Database if you try to again open it `sqlite3_open()`

or

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2()
```

this will result in  `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` regarding database .

```
 -(BOOL)containsPendingSignature
    {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = nil;

    const char* sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM pending_signatures";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error:'%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));


    int rowCount = 0;
    if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        rowCount = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    }

     sqlite3_finalize(statement);
     sqlite3_close(database);
    return rowCount > 0;
    }
```

i hope this will  help you ....

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to add `sqlite3_close(database);` but the error is still there.

Should I add this in previous functions as well?

Comment: You should add finalize and close statement  in all functions.